# Trying to set style of div using ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to change the background color of a div using ng-repeat. The color I am trying to pull from the object in the loop. Whenever I do this however it sets my style property equal to blank.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    <div ng-repeat="channel in channelObjects">
        <div class="mediumTile" style="background-color:#{{channel.Color}}">
           Channel Color: {{channel.color}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This displays my mediumTile object with the correct channel color displayed. By the style is set to nothing once the page loads

This is what the page displays:

```
<div class="mediumTile" style="">
     Channel Color: 123456 
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead of style, using style with interpolation will cause some browsers to strip the values off (invalid style attribute with the presence of `{{` etc..) before even angular has a chance to process it. This happens specifically in IE (not sure which browser you tested this).

```
<div class="mediumTile" ng-style="{'background-color':'#' + channel.color}">
```

Also mind the casing as well, `c`olor.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FegN8D?p=preview)**